# How to retrieve resources from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making my own testing application and want a login page on that. And when the user passes the credentials it should be **echo Success**.
but I didn't succeed in that.

So, first of all, I want to share my code with you guys. Please have a look.

```
<?php
define ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define ('DB_NAME', 'sqltest');
define ('DB_USER', 'sqltest');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'sqltest');

$conn=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die ("failed to connect to db". mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $conn) or die ("failed to connect to db". mysql_error());

$v1=@$_POST['username'];

$v2=@$_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username=".'$v1'. "AND password=.'$v2'."; 
$v3 = mysql_query($query);

if ($v3 === true){
    echo "success".$query;
}

else {
    echo "failed";
}?>
```

So, you can see the MySQL query with variable and I passed it to the **mysql_query** to initialize. And that query will check the **users credential ($v1, $v2)** in the database. And if the users credential found then **Success will be echo on the display otherwise Failed.**

But I only see failed on my screen. So what is the reason? I know there are lot of codes available on internet but I want my own

Is the query correct? Or something other.

I know there are a lot of mistakes in my PHP code. That's why I come here.

Please answer it with clarification.

Thank you, waiting for.....

Comment: just change this `".'$v1'. "` to `'$v1'` and this `.'$v2'.` to `'$v2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PHP variable is inside double quoted string it will be treated as variable and it's value will be used instead. But when variable is inside single quoted string variable will be treated as a string, not as variable, so it will not be parsed and it's value will not be used.

So instead of:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username=".'$v1'. "AND password=.'$v2'.";
```

where those `$v1` and `'$v2'` will NOT be parsed since they are inside single quoted strings you should have:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username='".$v1."' AND password='".$v2."'";
```

where variable is not inside the string at all. Notice that single quotes are moved to double quoted strings. Or even like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username='$v1' AND password='$v2'";
```

Where `$v1` and `$v2` are inside double quoted strings so they will be parsed. Don't get confused by single quote inside double quotes. Only first one used matters - second one is treated just a common character. So in my last example `$v1` and `$v2` are inside double quoted string and single quotes are just characters which are part of that string.

And of course, think about sql injections and at least escape values you collect from users before including them into your sql:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username='".addslashes($v1)."' AND password='".addslashes($v2)."'";
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Well explained. Okay, but I want to check the credential in the database so when I submit the valid credential it should echo "Found". And I explained in the question.

Comment: That $v3 variable will contain query results, check out it's content. Use i.e. print_r($v3) ; to see what you have there (in both cases...when user is recognizes and when not) and put some appropriate if statement depending on values print_r() showed to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your string quoting is wrong.  Here's the corrected line:

```
$query = "SELECT `username`, `password` FROM userinfo WHERE `username` = '$v1' AND `password` = '$v2'";
```

mysql_query doesn't return true on success, but it does return false on failure so you will also need to correct this line to:

```
if ($v3 !== false){
```

By the way:

- Your code has bad SQL injection vulnerabilities so I really hope you never intend to use it in a real web site
- mysql_* functions are deprecated so you shouldn't be writing new code that is dependent on them.

Comment: Hello @sg- Thanks for this, but it didn'r work as i want. i.e. When i type username and password is admin:admin display echo **found** which is  good, but when i submit the **adminn:adminn (i.e. wrong credentials)** is again says found?

Comment: There's no mention of "found" anywhere in your code.  Your question is about a query that fails to execute (ie: produces an error).  If it's now executing but producing the wrong results you should accept my answer and open another question for the new issue.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to accept it. Then should i mention another issue?

Comment: Sorry @sg- I am not accepting it. I read my question again and i mention all the problem. And please read the question once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
<?php
define ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define ('DB_NAME', 'sqltest');
define ('DB_USER', 'sqltest');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'sqltest');

$conn=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die ("failed to connect to db". mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $conn) or die ("failed to connect to db". mysql_error());

$v1=@$_POST['username'];

$v2=@$_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM userinfo WHERE username='$v1' AND password='$v2'"; 
$v3 = mysql_query($query);

if ($v3){
    echo "success";
}

else {
    echo "failed";
} ?>
```